# How to get the address/reference of a cell based on a filter Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

## Background

Suppose I would like to filter a column for a cell that contains the text  "onboarding". As soon as I get that, I want to use OFFSET to get the corresponding value in the I column as depicted below

[image: text]

## Question

How do I get the reference of a cell that is outputted as a result of a filter? For example I would run this command

```
=filter(data!C1:C100,data!C1:C100="onboarding")
```

But then I want to get the reference of the result (right now it just returns the string "onboarding") and feed it to the [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) method, which expects a cell_reference as a parameter

```
OFFSET(cell_reference, offset_rows, offset_columns, [height], [width])
```

Comment: The background and specially the image as it has a red label that says "... I want to get the corresponding value in the I column" are misleading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Short answer

To get a cell reference relative to a filter result, try

```
=INDIRECT(INDEX("I"&filter(ROW(data!C1:C100),data!C1:C100="onboarding")),1))
```

## Explanation

- `ROW(data!C1:C100)` returns the row number for each cell in the referred range
- `FILTER` will return the corresponding values to the criteria.
- `&` concatenates  `I` as the column ID with the values returned by filter.
- `INDEX` is used to force only one result<sup>1</sup>.
- `INDIRECT` converts the reference string to a reference that could be used by `OFFSET` or other functions that require a reference as argument.

<sup>1</sup>: The use of `INDEX` is optional as `INDIRECT` only will return one reference. If `INDEX` is omitted, the reference will be related to the first value returned by `FILTER`.

Comment: hey Ruben is there a way I can reach you directly? My email is abdullah.bakhach@gmail.com

Comment: I just sent you a Hangouts invitation.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.. but i'll award correct answer to reference answer

```
=vlookup($A$2,data!$C$1:$I$100,7,false)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you just want the values from I that has Onboarding in C then use:

```
=filter(data!I1:I100,data!C1:C100="onboarding")
```

Comment: Read the question please

Comment: You do state that you want the corresponding value from I. My suggestion will do that. You do not explain why you want to use offset.

Comment: The question is about how to get a reference string (address), not a value. (The background and included image are misleading)